# PyQt5 QNetworkReply stops updating of continuous response when in signal handler

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm trying to continuously get frames from this server:

```py
def get_feed():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.06)
        buffer = get_shot()
        buffer = buffer.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n'
               b'Content-Length: ' + str(len(buffer)).encode() + '\r\n\r\n' + 
               buffer + b'\r\n')
               
               
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return Response(get_feed(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

For that I use this code:

```py
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, test.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self._source_url = QUrl("*link_here*")
        self._image_request = QNetworkRequest(self._source_url)
        self._network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self._image_reply = self._network_manager.get(self._image_request)
        ...

        self.frameTimer = QTimer(self)
        self.timeBetweenFrames = 1
        self.timeBetweenReads = 0.06
        self.frameTimer.timeout.connect(self.updateFrame)
        self.frameTimer.start(self.timeBetweenFrames)
        ...

    def updateFrame(self):
        # Get how many bytes do I need to read for the frame
        content_length = 0
        buff = self._image_reply.readAll()
        frameSizeAddress = buff.lastIndexOf(b'Content-Length:') + len(b'Content-Length: ')
        frameSizeEndAddress = buff[frameSizeAddress:].indexOf(b'\r\n')
        
        if frameSizeAddress == -1 or frameSizeEndAddress == -1:
            self.frameTimer.start(self.timeBetweenFrames)
            return
        
        frameSize = int(str(buff[frameSizeAddress:frameSizeAddress+frameSizeEndAddress], 'utf-8'))
        frameBegin = frameSizeAddress + frameSizeEndAddress + 4
        
        imageBuffer = buff[frameBegin:frameBegin+frameSize]
        readenBytes = len(imageBuffer)
        
        # If the image came partially
        while(readenBytes < frameSize):
            time.sleep(self.timeBetweenReads)
            buff = self._image_reply.read(frameSize-readenBytes)
            imageBuffer += buff[:frameSize-readenBytes]
            readenBytes = len(imageBuffer)
            print(len(buff))
```

And here comes the problem. If the image came partially it will never be read. Last print always give 0.

If use read(1024) instead of readAll() during first read here

```
content_length = 0
buff = self._image_reply.readAll()
```

Then everything works but if frames come faster then the app reads them: they begin stacking and delay between feed and display-image becomes bigger and bigger.

For me it looks like QNetworkReply doesn't update when it is in signal handler, so server do not write in it new bytes.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I cannot obviously test your code, but I'd start by saying that you should certainly **not** use `time.sleep`: it completely blocks the event loop, preventing *anything* in the program to process events (including the network manager to properly do its job). You should keep the buffer as a persistent instance attribute and eventually update at future calls. Note that a 1ms timeout is a bit pointless, and probably completely unnecessary: if the stream is continuous, you should be able to just work with the reply's `readyRead()`.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the advice! `You should keep the buffer as a persistent instance attribute and eventually update at future calls` how can I do that?

Comment: @musicamante I tried to do `self._image_reply.waitForReadyRead(1000)` instead of `time.sleep` and it freezes because nothing is in the reply.

Comment: `waitForReadyRead` is obviously blocking just like `time.sleep`. I *specifically* wrote `readyRead`, which is a *signal*.